# Power Bi Soap Request

Tags: powerbi

I have a web service which uses soap actions to retrieve data. How can I add such a request to use inside `Power BI`. I tied Get Data from Web, but it seems I only can add request headers but no body.

```
POST /subtarget/SERVICE.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://methods.org/GetProducts"
Content-Length: 559

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetProducts xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <username>name</username>
      <password>pass</password>
      <supplierId>313</supplierId>
    </GetProducts>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `body` to `Web.Contents` as a second argument, using `[Content = Body]`.

I have used `http://dneonline.com/calculator.asmx` to demonstrate, the request is quite simple, it will add two numbers.

**Steps**

1. Define your `SOAP` envelope inside your PowerQuery. Remove any unnecessary whitespaces, and transform single quotes `"` to double quotes `""`. Let's save this into a variable called `SoapEnvelope`.
2. Transform your `SOAPEnvelope` into binary using `Text.ToBinary`.
3. Construct the `Web.Contents` using `Content` with the the transformed `SOAPEnvelope` and the Header,  in this case you only need `#"Content-type" = 'text/xml'`.
4. Wrap your `Web.Contents` into an XML content to display as `Table`.

```
let
  SOAPEnvelope= 
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
<soap:Body><Add xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
<intA>1</intA>
<intB>2</intB></Add>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>",
  Source = Xml.Document(
    Web.Contents(
      "http://dneonline.com/calculator.asmx",
      [Content = Text.ToBinary(SOAPEnvelope), Headers = [#"Content-Type" = "text/xml"]]
    )
  )
in
  Source
```

Comment: When I try to add host and content-length headers it will give me such an error: `Expression.Error: The Host header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.`

Comment: You should avoid using `Host` and `Content-Length`, as far as I know, those are added automatically by PowerBI.